# Force software-based OpenGL rendering on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opengl

How may I force an application to use software-based OpenGL rendering on Ubuntu?

Comment: What (kind of) application are we talking about?

Answer (score 25):

If you're using Mesa's `libGL`, you can enable software rendering permanently by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-swx11
```

This will remove the [`libgl1-mesa-glx`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libgl1-mesa-glx) hardware-accelerated Mesa libraries and install the software-only renderer.

Alternately, you can set `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1`, which will only affect programs started with that environment variable, not the entire system.

Both these changes may not work if you're using the binary NVidia drivers, which supply their own `libGL`.

Comment: Hi, where can I set this variable LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1? I have the inverse problem, OpenGL is always software rendered and my laptop does not support Unity3D for ubuntu 15.04. I have  hybrid Intel-Nvidia graphics.

Comment: libgl1-mesa-swx11 no longer replaces libgl1-mesa-glx.  Thus when installing it you need to configure an override to use it.  
Still, I recommend using the LLVM-Pipe Software rendering using "LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 " It's much faster and takes advantage of newer hardware.  
Also, users of nvidia and amd drivers can force the use of the mesa software pipeline, if mesa is installed, through using an ld.so hack to override the libGL library that is loaded.

Comment: Does this work on AMD proprietary drivers? Is there an easy option on Nvidia?

Comment: I wonder why `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` could not be made to work with NVIDIA drivers installed + `libgl1-mesa-glx`, since my program is still linked to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` (provided by `libgl1-mesa-dev`) and not `/usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGL.so`, which seems to be loaded with `dlopen` by Mesa. Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 4):

If you use NVIDIA drivers by default, then you also need `__GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=mesa` (in addition to `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1`). I tested on fully updated Arch Linux (NVIDIA 470.57.02).

```bash
env __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=mesa LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 glxinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is about your own application, you can link to the software OpenGL implementation [Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/).