# Use a remote linux bloated graphical application from OS X

Tags: linux, macos, remote-desktop

I need to use remotely some graphical application in a linux machine. For very basic applications, I just connect remotely from my OS X Lion using

```
ssh -X machine:
```

and then

```
./gedit &
```

and it works. But for more complex graphical applications, they hang up constantly and I get the error:

```
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display "localhost:11.0".
```

I wonder how could I circumvent this. Somebody recommended vncserver and vncclient, while others X -query

Comment: Hello. NV-GLX is a part of NVidia's binary driver package. There have been some problems with the latest version of Nvidia's driver (295.10). It causes hangs and segfaults in some applications. Could you switch to Nouveau driver and see if the error persists? P.S. Did you try running the same apps on the Linux box? Do you get the same errors?

Comment: in a linux ubuntu box i got the same problem (well, it was in the same machine under a virtual machine)

Comment: how could I switch to Nouveau driver? Would I kill OSX Lion?

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly: You have Physical machine (MAC) with MAC OS X Lion and a Physical machine with Ubuntu. Is this correct?

Comment: No. I have a macbook pro running os x lion. Underneath a virtualmachine running ubuntu. So it us the same problem since in this case the VM accesses the graphics with the same problematic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the capability detection of your X application breaks down somewhere - it wants to use GL rendering, but the X server will have none of it. Can you please try setting `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` in the environment? That should force your application to not use hardware rendering for OpenGL.

Have a look at this one here:
[Force software based opengl rendering](https://superuser.com/questions/106056/force-software-based-opengl-rendering)

Comment: I tried setting the flag, but get the same error, will have a look at the link

Comment: not all apps honor the env. Does it maybe have command line switches to disable OpenGL acceleration?

Comment: unfortunately not, as far as I can see. I also tried from a linux machine, installing the GL software driver but same error, seems to be application scpefici error